# How to calculate the Feigenbaum constant via Matlab

Tags: matlab, constants

I am currently trying to calculate the feigenbaum constant via matlab and tried to follow instructions from Brigg's paper 
(Keith Briggs, How to calculate the feigenbaum constant, 1989)

http://keithbriggs.info/documents/how-to-calc.pdf

And my current program looks as follows:

The subfunction (using the newton iteration) is:

```
function [ c ] = constant( m,n,c)
%m: gives the number of iteration for the bifurcationvalue (limit)
%n: gives the bifurcation degree
%c: is the starting value for the bifurcationvalue

N=2^n;
for j=1:m
    x=0;
    dx=0;
    for i=1:N 
        x=x^2-c;
        dx=2*x*dx-1;
    end
    c=c-(x/dx);
end
```

And the delta calculating function is:

```
function [ d ] = delta( N)
%N: gives the iteration of calculating delta (d)
%d: delta - the feigenbaum constant

c(1)=0;
c(2)=1;
d=3.2;
    for i=3:N
        s=c(i-1)+((c(i-1)-c(i-2))/d);
        c(i)=constant(500,i-1,s);
        d=(c(i-1)-c(i-2))/(c(i)-c(i-1));
    end
end
```

Now my first c (input N=3) corresponds to the first value in the paper (in the paper it's noted as a2), but the further calculated values of c just don't change and hence the feigenbaum constant cannot be calculated accurately. 
Does anyone have any ideas, what the problem could be?
Or does anyone have another approach how to calculate delta via matlab?

Comment: How both function are communating with each other? From looking rapidly, i thought `dx` in the `constant` function should be the `d` from the `delta` function? Try to show us how both function are called.

Comment: function constant(m,n,c) is used in the function delta(N) (in the line 8).
The constant function calculates the roots (vector c) of the iteration function x^2-c and hence dx is the derivative of the iteration function. 
The delta function calculates the ratio of the roots which should be the delta d. 
My problem is that the c's do not match with the values in the paper (my c's are the a's in the paper) and I just don't know why :(

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while to understand the equations but I believe I've found your problem.  In the `constant()` function, in this pair of equations:

```
x = x^2 - c;
dx = 2 * x * dx - 1;
```

the second equation needs the old `x` value from before the first equation.  I.e. these two equations are in the reverse (wrong) order.  The Python code I wrote to work this out:

```
def constant(m, n, a):
    # m: gives the number of iteration for the bifurcationvalue (limit)
    # n: gives the bifurcation degree
    # a: is the starting value for the bifurcationvalue

    N = 2 ** n

    for _ in range(m):
        b = 0
        b_prime = 0

        for _ in range(N):
            b_prime = 1 - 2 * b_prime * b
            b = a - b ** 2

        a -= b / b_prime

    return a

def delta(N):
    # N: gives the iteration of calculating delta (d)
    # d: delta - the feigenbaum constant

    a = [0, 1]
    d = 3.2

    print("{:^3}\t{:^12}\t{:^16}".format("i", "a_i", "delta_i"))

    for i in range(2, N + 1):
        approximation = a[-1] + ((a[-1] - a[-2]) / d)
        a.append(constant(500, i, approximation))
        d = (a[-2] - a[-3]) / (a[-1] - a[-2])

        print("{:>3}\t{:12.10f}\t{:16.14f}".format(i, a[-1], d))

delta(13)
```

My equations are different than yours as I reworked this from source document you linked.  I believe your equations are equivalent, just in the wrong order.

**OUTPUT**

```
% python3 test.py
 i      a_i             delta_i     
  2 1.3107026413    3.21851142203809
  3 1.3815474844    4.38567759856834
  4 1.3969453597    4.60094927653812
  5 1.4002530812    4.65513049539159
  6 1.4009619629    4.66611194782316
  7 1.4011138049    4.66854858147197
  8 1.4011463258    4.66906066094185
  9 1.4011532908    4.66917155283517
 10 1.4011547825    4.66919515622284
 11 1.4011551020    4.66920020063980
 12 1.4011551704    4.66920165152360
 13 1.4011551851    4.66920008124221
%
```

Comment: a_i are point ( c =a) for which period N cycle is superstable ( in the other words centers of the hyperbolic components of the Mandelbrot set)